# bus error: 10. C code, malloc example

Tags: c, bus, memory-segmentation

When I try compiling the following C code, i get a bus error. 
I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I have called memcpy, however I cant figure it out. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    char *p = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*11); 
    // Assign some value to p
    p = "hello";


    char *name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*11);
    // Assign some value to name
    name = "Bye";

    memcpy (p,name,sizeof(char)*10); // Problem begins here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other remarks: [Don't cast the return value of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/). Why are you using `memcpy` for copying *strings* when `strncpy` and similar functions exist for that purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here `p` points to a string literal after your assignment, NOT to your allocated memory!

Then you try to write into that memory with `memcpy`.

Many C compilers allocate string literals in read-only memory, hence the bus error.

To fix your problem, you should *copy* the characters h, e, l, l, and o into the space you allocated for `p` in the first line of `main`, using `strncpy`.  This keeps `p` pointing to the memory you allocated yourself; the later `memcpy` will be fine (provided you don't overflow your buffer of course).

Note that in general when you assign to a string variable directly you are making the variable point to a different memory address.  In your code you have allocated space for a couple of strings but when you assign string literals to the variables, you are changing the location to which they point, causing a memory leak.

Comment: Is there any way to write on p ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been trying to figure this out for a while now!

Comment: Shouldn't the code return a `seg fault` and not a `bus error`?  Bus errors are memory access(es) the CPU cannot physically address while seg faults are memory access(es) the CPU cannot logically address (i.e. OP's problem).

Comment: You get different errors with different compilers and different OSes for the same problem. For the OP's exact code, if you run it on JDoodle for C99, you get `Command terminated by signal 11`. On my Mac with clang (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)) I get `Bus error: 10`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, that `p = "hello"` the `"hello"` return a pointer which point to a string `hello` and the hello can't be change. You use `p = "hello"` means make `p` point to this string too. So when you try to change it, you will get an error. 
The right way is like follows:
`char a[] = "hello";`   or

```
char *a = malloc(sizeof(char)*11); /*cast is not good*/
strcpy (a, "hello");
```

BTW, use `malloc` had better NOT using cast like `(char *)` or `(int *)`.